# How to pass the value of an array to a mathematical function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a defined mathematical function: `f =Inline('x1^2+x2^2+2*x1*x2','x1','x2')`

and I have an array that represents the number value of x1 and x2. (e.g. the array is `A=[1 2]`)

I want to automate the process of getting the `f(x1,x2)`, but I couldn't figure out the right way that Matlab can take in the array and assign values to `x1` and `x2`.

What can I do to pass in the array values to the mathematical model and get the function value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [anonymous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) functions instead of [inline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html) since `inline` will be removed in a future release of MATLAB.

Example (from the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)):

```
sqr = @(x) x.^2;
a = sqr(5)
a =
   25
```

In your case:

```
f = @(x) x(1)^2+x(2)^2+2*x(1)*x(2);
```

Now it expects x to be a two (or more) value array.

```
A = [1 2];
f(A) =
    9
```

**Note:**

I don't have MATLAB on my home computer so I haven't actually tested this but it should get you going in the right direction. Have a look over the docs and you'll be fine.

Comment: `x[1]`? Were you just programming in Python maybe?